# Ionic error Geolocation ionic Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(…) is not a function TypeError: Object(…) is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, dictionary, ionic-framework

While importing `Geolocation`:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
```

Gettin error:

> ionic Geolocation :Ionic v4 Uncaught TypeError: Object(…) is not a
>   function

Comment: share your pacakge.json content and checkout [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

this error occured when cordova plugin is not installed you need to install cordova plugin and reserve project

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm install @ionic-native/geolocation
```